# How to export all certificates in a certificate chain to separate .crt files with a single command

Tags: command-line, openssl

I would like to export all certificates in a certificate chain to separate `.crt` files with a single command. How can I do that?

To provide some background information:

1. I would like to use the `openssl` bash utility: `(openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <host>:<port> & sleep 4)`
2. the above command **may** print more than one certificate, that is, it may print more than one string with the following pattern: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` X.509 certificate encoded in base64 `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. For example:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIFNzCCAx+gAwIBAgITUwAAAAJpqCKn3YTQ6gAAAAAAAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF...
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
3. the contents of the `.crt` files should be exactly the printed base64 encoded certificates, including tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `awk` can be used to solve the problem:

`(openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <host>:<port> & sleep 4) | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{if(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/){a++}; out="/tmp/<host>"a".crt"; print > out}'`

Replace `<host>` and `<port>` with actual values. The `sleep` command is there to limit the timeout of the `openssl` command.

Comment: Why run `awk` under `sudo`? It makes the vulnerability whereby you're opening files with predictable names in `/tmp` with O_CREAT and without O_EXCL or O_NOFOLLOW much worse. Why the `& sleep 4`.

Comment: Replace `& sleep 4` with `<<< echo`

Answer (score 2):

Pipe into `awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > "cert-" i ".crt" }'`

For example:

```
echo "" | 
    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 |
    awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > "cert-" i ".crt"  }'
```

Comment: It is always better to include a more limiting search expression when dealing with string search. That is why I will choose my response as an answer.